# Fitch Question Please Help Me

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

I'm having trouble understanding writing out a proof. The proof I'm trying to work with is :
[image]
How do I reach this goal? Which rules do I use and with which support steps to each rule (proofs to prove each step?) Using only inference rules, reit, quantifier rules. What have I missed writing out?

Comment: My calculation was completely wrong so look directly at grahams comment and what he has put up for correct explanations!

Comment: This is the third context-less question you've asked about Fitch-style proofs.

Answer (score 1):

On line 9 referencing conjunction elimination from line 8 should derive either *B(a)* or *K(a)*, but not *R(a)*.

You might start this with the assumption on line 8 which is made to hopefully eliminate the existential in line 2.

Then use conjunction elimination to derive *B(a)* from that assumption. Use universal elimination from line 1 to derive *B(a) → R(a)*. Those two lines allow one to derive *R(a)*. Use conjunction elimination to get *K(a)* and then conjunction introduction to combine *R(a) ∧ K(a)*. Use existential introduction to turn that into *∃x(R(x) ∧ K(x))*.

That will allow you to discharge the assumption using existential elimination to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the skeleton for the proof.  You begin by assuming a witness to the existential in the premises, aiming to derive a witness for the existential in the conclusion.

```
  |  Ɐx (Bx → Rx)      Premise
  |_ Ǝx (Bx ˄ Kx)      Premise
  |  |_ [c] Bc ˄ Kc    Assumption
  |  |  :              ˄E
  |  |  :              ˄E
  |  |  :              ⱯE
  |  |  :              →E
  |  |  Kc ˄ Rc        ˄I
  |  |  Ǝx (Kx ˄ Rx)   ƎI
  |  Ǝx (Kx ˄ Rx)      ƎE
```

Comment: thank you so much graham! Could you please tell me the : steps as well and which steps I should higlight to each step?

Comment: Please, try to do it for yourself first.  @maxpax

Comment: I did, and the way I tried it turned out like the one above, so I'm completely lost and not sure what to do? Unfortunately, I'm not gifted in this at all.

Comment: @maxpax The first two suggestions are ˄E, conjunction elimination.  So what conditional(s) are there to be eliminated? What two derivations could result?

Comment: Thank you graham! It's all figured out!